# htacess URL Rewriting Username in the URL conflicts with other Rewritten URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Okay, So I am creating a site where a user can create Profiles. I want the User Profiles to be like http://example.com/username but the problem is that it conflicts with other Rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule story/(.*)/ story.php?id=$1
RewriteRule story/(.*) story.php?id=$1

#Profiles:
RewriteRule (.*)/ profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?id=$1
```

Now, what happens is that when I try to visit http://example.com/story/hello_world The system thinks that 'story' in the URL is the UserName and searches for it in the Database and then throws the 404 Page(as expected).

I dont want user pages like example.com/user/username .

**Example: Digg.com has digg.com/story and digg.com/username**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace both of your rules with the rule below to prevent the problem with http://example.com/story/hello_world being interpreted as a user.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/])+/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you have more specific rules on username, e.g. username is alphanumeric and between 5-10 characters long, then a better rule would be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10})/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```